# Running Redmine with ruby 2.1.1

Tags: ruby, redmine, ruby-2.1

I have installed ruby 2.1.1 using rvm after root login. In another user login ruby 1.8.7 is in use. with 1.8.7 Redmine 2.5.0 works fine. but with 2.1.0

---

command:

```
ruby script/rails server webrick -d -e production
```

---

error:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:252:in `require': /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/vpim-0.695/lib/vpim/vcard.rb:679: invalid multibyte escape: /^\xFE\xFF/ (SyntaxError)
invalid multibyte escape: /^\xFF\xFE/
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:252:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:237:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:252:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/vpim-0.695/lib/vpim.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler.rb:131:in `require'
    from /home/dax/redmine-2.5.0/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: it looks like authors know about it http://www.redmine.org/issues/16194

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the gem vpim with this command:

```
gem uninstall vpim
```

I've tried an installation and don't need this gem.

If you really need that gem edit the file

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/vpim-0.695/lib/vpim/vcard.rb
```

and place this in the **first** line:

```
# encoding: US-ASCII
```

Comment: the same problem even after `# encoding: US-ASCII`

Comment: @DaxJoshi Sorry my mistake in gem commnad. I've corrected it. Try with '# encoding: ISO-8859-1'

Comment: #ISO-8859-1 was there actually.

Comment: after uninstalling it shows `Could not find vpim-0.695 in any of the sources`. As it needs it.

Answer (score 1):

The `vpim` gem mentioned in your stack trace is not a requirement of core Redmine. It seems you have a custom plugin which requires that gem and which is not compatible with newer Ruby versions (i.e. anything >= 1.9).

To solve this issue, you thus need to update or remove that custom plugin. Also, right now, it is probably a good idea to not use Ruby 2.1 but Ruby 2.0 as it seems that Redmine core (or more generally, Rails 3.2) still has other issues with Ruby 2.1.1.